# Modify date of input to pass it to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Dapp where a user creates his own activity, one of the required fields to create the activity is the start and the end where the user puts the time of start and end of his activity.

[image]

The output is a string like this `hours:minutes` so if the user selected 9 o'clock the output will be like this `9:00`. The problem is that im using solidity for the backend of my dapp and i cant pass the time like this `9:00`  i need to pass it as a number how can i do that with javascript or other libraries (For the frontend im using ReactJS)

**Ouput of Input Date:**

`9:30`

**What i need:**

`9:30`  -> `930`

I tried to look at other questions but i couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undersatnd the problem right, all you have to do is to strip the string of `:` symbol. You can do that easily with `string.replace` function.

```
const handleSubmitActivity = (activity) => {
  activity.time = activity.time.replace(":", "");
  // activity.time = Number(activity.time.replace(":", "")); if you need number instead of string
  // send to the backend
}
```

Comment: if i wanted to to the opposite (1340 -> 13:40) this approach wouldn't work. is there an other method to the the opposite?

Comment: Sure, @Shadq. If you work with time, that always have 4 digits (or 3), you can convert the  number into string and insert `:`. Something like this:
```ts
const time = 1340;
let timeString = `${time}`;

if (timeString.length === 3) {
  timeString = `${timeString.slice(0, 1)}:${timeString.slice(1)}`;
} else {
  timeString = `${timeString.slice(0, 2)}:${timeString.slice(2)}`;
}
```

Comment: There's actually a more concise way of doing this. I can't edit the previous comment so I uploaded a better version here: https://pastebin.com/8CiYhY0X